# Is there a standard for OTPs tied to transaction details (that has been implemented in apps/devices)?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, banks, totp

There are standards for Time-based (TOTP) and Counter-based (HOTP) One Time Password schemes.
Generated OTPs are independent of the transactions they are used for, such as authorizing a login or a money transfer.

These are widely supported by smartphone apps (e.g. Google Authenticator) and hardware tokens (e.g. Yubikeys), and used by many online services.

---

On the other hand, many financial institutions (particularly within the EU due to the recently adopted PSD2's *Dynamic Linking* requirement) are implementing schemes that tie the OTP generation to specific transaction data (such as amount and recipient in a money transfer) - to be verified by the user on their generator device/app.
Apart from SMS and push notification options, many institutions offer some kind of visual screen-to-device transfer method, such as flickering bar codes, or (sometimes proprietary) 2D matrix/QR codes.

Public documentation on banking mechanisms is notoriously scarce, so I have not been able to find any details on these presumably proprietary schemes.

I have so far found one documented way to use such a scheme for my own purposes, which is the TxOTP feature of the [Authy app](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/transactional-time-based-one-time-passwords).
But this is a commercial service involving a remote API (Authy) that is hardly necessary from a technical standpoint.

Is there any public standard that defines such a *Transactional* OTP scheme with a visual transfer?
Preferrably one that has been implemented in smartphone apps similarly to TOTP and HOTP.

Comment: Just curious, why *flickering* barcodes?

Comment: @Ahmad Because a single barcode doesn't have enough capacity to contain all transaction details. I have mostly seen this format in use with dedicated generator devices (like seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_authentication_number#ChipTAN_/_Sm@rt-TAN_/_CardTAN)) that use the bank card (smartcard) to generate a OTP.
On the top edge, they have an array of photosensors that can read a sequency of 5-wide barcodes from screen. This design is probably much cheaper than using a sensor capable of reading a static data matrix.

Comment: See also [Is 3DS compatible with secure 2FA technologies? (TOTP, WebAuthn)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/273801/is-3ds-compatible-with-secure-2fa-technologies-totp-webauthn?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: See also [Does SQRL satisfy PSD2 SCA requirements for "dynamic linking"?](https://sqrl.grc.com/threads/does-sqrl-satisfy-psd2-sca-requirements-for-dynamic-linking.1276/)

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two open standards that satisfy the PSD2's Dynamic Linking requirement:

1. SQRL
2. WebAuthn

#### SQRL

[SQRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQRL) is an open standard for auth released under the public domain by Steve Gibson and the SQRL team.

- https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm

| [image: Prompt Titled "From: www.grc.com". Body: Please confirm that you are authorizing the transfer of One Hundred Thousand US Dollars ($100,000) from your account to the numbered account: 3405-5942-3327 in the Cayman Islands. [DO NOT TRANSFER!! Abortt!!] or [Yes - Transfer the Funds]] |
| --- |
| The 2019 SQRL "ask" facility predates the PSD2 "dynamic linking" requirement by 2 years. Source: https://www.grc.com/sqrl/SQRL_Explained.pdf |

Originally released in October 2019, [SQRL has included a robust "ask" feature that has satisfied the Dynamic Linking](https://sqrl.grc.com/threads/does-sqrl-satisfy-psd2-sca-requirements-for-dynamic-linking.1276/) requirement 2 years before it was enforced by PSD2 (in 2021).

At the time of writing (2024), there are open-source client-side SQRL apps available for Windows, Linux, iOS, Android, Chromium, and Firefox. There are also server-side implementations available in .NET, Drupal, Wordpress, and OAuth2.

#### WebAuthn

[WebAuthn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAuthn) is an [open standard](https://www.w3.org/copyright/software-license-2023/) developed by the [FIDO Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDO_Alliance) and [W3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium).

- https://w3c.github.io/secure-payment-confirmation/

| [image: Prompt titled "Use Touch ID to verify and complete your purchase?". Store: merchant.com. Payment: Mastercard ****4444. Total: $20.00 USD. [Cancel] or [Verify]] |
| --- |
| WebAuthn was extended to support "dynamic linking" in 2021 with Secure Payment Confirmation. Source: https://github.com/w3c/secure-payment-confirmation |

In [2021](https://www.w3.org/standards/history/secure-payment-confirmation/), WebAuthn [was extended](https://www.w3.org/news/2023/call-for-implementations-secure-payment-confirmation-published-as-a-w3c-candidate-recommendation/) to include [Secure Payment Confirmation](https://w3c.github.io/secure-payment-confirmation/), a Web API that was [specifically created](https://github.com/w3c/secure-payment-confirmation/blob/main/explainer.md) for the WebAuthn standard to support transaction confirmations that are compatible with the PSD2 dynamic linking requirements.

While it's expected that open-source, client-side hardware tokens (eg [Nitrokeys](https://www.nitrokey.com/products/nitrokeys)) that implement the WebAuthn API will be capable to support transaction confirmations that satisfy the PSD2 "dynamic linking" requirement via Secure Payment Confirmation, it's [currently not documented (as of 2024) how to confirm which devices (and user agents) are required](https://github.com/w3c/secure-payment-confirmation/issues/266).